# Relationships Not Displaying in Grid

Tags: relationships, grid

I've got a project where I need to display several sales reps dependent upon their location. I've decided to display that data with relationships within a grid. The entire set up is like this:

**Channel** - Rep Locator {rep_locator}

**Grid** - Rep Grid {rep_grid}

**Grid Fields**

*Text Input* - Location {location} | *Relationship* - Sales Rep {sales_rep}

**Relationship Channel**

Has a title {title}, Office Number {office_number}, and Email {email_address}.

---

I can get the Location just fine, it also loops out the correct amount of relationship entries, but it does not display the title, office number or anything else.

My code is set up as

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="rep_locator" dynamic="no" disable="members|categories|pagination"}
{rep_grid}
     <div class="region" data-query="{rep_grid:location}">
        <h2>{rep_grid:location}</h2>
        {rep_grid:sales_rep}
            <span class="individual-rep">
             <h3>{rep_grid:sales_rep:title}</h3>
        </span>
        {rep_grid:sales_rep}
     </div>
{/rep_grid}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From they code that you posed, you are not closing your {rep_grid:sales_rep} tag:

```
    {rep_grid:sales_rep}
        <span class="individual-rep">
            <h3>{rep_grid:sales_rep:title}</h3>
        </span>
    {/rep_grid:sales_rep}
```

Comment: Man I knew it was something simple. Coding alone gets tough some times.